# getConfig().set does not work correctly?

Tags: java, config, bukkit

I'm trying to make "`/setspawn`" command "`/lv setspawn`". I put the plugin inside "plugins" folder, the plugin generates the config and I'll open the config. Everything at this moment is right, so when I try to use "`/lv setspawn`" everything except cords get removed. I go to config  and use "<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>"  "<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>" and  `/reload`. Now config is like at the first moment, I use again "`/lv setspawn`" and works perfectly (I can't put more than 2 links).

I'm sorry for my english.

**What I want**:

I want the coordinates are put inside the config when I use `/lv setspawn`

[Video from the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_14IMS6TiHo)

Main code :

```
package com.gmail.santiagoelheroe;

import static com.gmail.santiagoelheroe.Eventos.plugin;
import org.bukkit.*;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class LoginVip extends JavaPlugin {

    // Comandos     
    @Override   
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")) {
            getConfig().set("Cords.World", player.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
            getConfig().set("Cords.X", player.getLocation().getX());
            getConfig().set("Cords.Y", player.getLocation().getY());
            getConfig().set("Cords.Z", player.getLocation().getZ());
            saveConfig();     
            sender.sendMessage(prefix + "§aSpawn placed");
            return true;
        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")) {
            World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(getConfig().getString("Cords.World"));  
            double x = getConfig().getDouble("Cords.X");
            double y = getConfig().getDouble("Cords.Y");
            double z = getConfig().getDouble("Cords.Z");
            player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
            return true;    
        }
        return true;        
   }


//Comandos   


   @Override
   public void onEnable() {  
       PluginManager manager = this.getServer().getPluginManager();
       manager.registerEvents(Eventos, this);
       saveDefaultConfig();   
   }
```

Config (inside the plugin)

```
# * Permisos: 'lv.main', 'lv.join' y 'lv.quit'  Variables: %player%
Configuracion:
  JoinMessage: '&b%player% &7se ha conectado'
  JoinMessageActivo: true
  QuitMessage: '&c%player% &7se ha desconectado'
  QuitMessageActivo: true
  NoPermissionsMessage: '&cNo tienes permisos para hacer esto'
  Prefix: '&7[&6LV&7] '
  TpSpawnOnJoin: false #To set spawn use in game /lv setspawn
Cords:
  World: ''
  X: ''
  Y: ''
  Z: ''
```

Comment: I also don't know english very well, here is what I do when I ask a question. 1) I write in sentence case. 2) I use Google Translator. 3) I spend lot of hours on it. This is very important.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, but I'm guessing you forgot to `saveConfig()` after `.set()`.

Comment: When i use "/lv setspawn"   first time everything except the cords get removed, but the second time not ,Please look carefully at the video.

Comment: Imports, permissions... this is not relevant. **Algorithm** is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I hate the default config so I never use it.
Take a look at [`YamlConfiguration`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.html). See a [tutorial](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tutorial-custom-yml-files.259122/).

```
File fileConfig = new File(Plugin.getDataFolder().getPath(), "config.yml");
YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(fileConfig);
```

---

```
// Setting
Location spawn = Player.getLocation();
config.set("spawn.world", spawn.getWorld().getName());
config.set("spawn.x", spawn.getX());
config.set("spawn.y", spawn.getY());
config.set("spawn.z", spawn.getZ());
config.set("spawn.yaw", spawn.getYaw());
config.set("spawn.pitch", spawn.getPitch());
try {
    config.save(fileConfig);
} catch (IOException io) {
    // Unable to save data
}

// Getting
String world = config.getString("spawn.world");
double x = config.getDouble("spawn.x");
double y = config.getDouble("spawn.y");
double z = config.getDouble("spawn.z");
double yaw = config.getDouble("spawn.yaw");
double pitch = config.getDouble("spawn.pitch");
Location spawn = new Location(Server.getWorld(world), x, y, z, (float) yaw, (float) pitch);
Player.teleport(spawn);
```

Comment: So how i can create 2 files ? "config.yml" "spawn.yml"

Comment: Use multiple variables.

Comment: And how i can reload that ? reloadConfig(); ?

Comment: Call `YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(File)` again.

Comment: So to create anything inside config i just have to use "**config.set("Config.JoinMessage, "%player% joined the game");**"
and to get string what i have to do ? "**config.getConfig().getString("Config.JoinMessage")**"

Comment: `config` is the variable of type `YamlConfiguration`, that has the `getString(String)` method.

Comment: Just 1 more thing how i can get the string from another class ?

Comment: You can make `YamlConfiguration` a static variable.